# Publishing normals in ROS

Tags: python, ros, normals, rospy, pcl

I'm new to the ROS and i have a struggle with the normals. So here is my situation.

I subscribe to my camera (realsense camera), I get the point cloud, I convert the point cloud from ROS_to_pcl and finally I use the function make_NormalEstimation() of python_pcl to get the normals. So far so good!
Now I want to publish somehow these normals to a ROS topic and by publishing i mean visualizing them also in RVIZ. The python_pcl function make_NormalEstimation() returns 4 values in the form of a vector. The 3 first values are normal_x, normal_y, normal_z and the 4th value is the curvature. I want to publish and visualize the normals in RVIZ through PoseStamed messages. As far as i know a PoseStamped message needs a Pose and a Quaternion. For the Pose field i use the x, y, z of the desired point in my point cloud i want to find the normal. But when it comes for the quaternion (and here is my main problem and struggle) i don't know what to use! I tried to use the returned values as they were quaternion_x, quaternion_y, quaernion_z, quaternion_w but the results where not so good...

So. my questions are:

- How can i use the returned values of make_NormalEstimation() to
  create a PoseStamed message?
- Is there a way to transform the returned values into quaternion?
- Am i missing something about the returned values?
- Is there another way of finding and using normals in ROS?
- How can i generate and publish a normal in ROS? Not only it's
  normal_x, normal_y, normal_z values but also it's orientation.
- Do i have to publish both it's normal_x, normal_y, normal_z and
  orientation or just it's normal_x, normal_y, normal_z values? And
  if so how will a robot know the orientation it needs to approach a
  point of interest?

Sorry for the chaos in my questions! I really hope they make sense!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you could provide some code and other data to help understand your problem..

Comment: Yes, sorry for the chaos in my post. I edited it to make my question more clear. My code is a little bit long to post it here but if you steal need it i will try to add it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply setup a publisher and create messages on demand for every normal in your list.

```
import rospy
from geometry_msgs import PoseStamped

pose_pub = rospy.Publisher('/normals_topic', PoseStamped, queue_size=10)
def calc_and_publish():
    #Calculate your normals
    norms = calculate_norms()

    for n in norms:
        output_pose = PoseStamped
        output_pose.pose.position.x = n[0]
        output_pose.pose.position.y = n[1]
        output_pose.pose.position.z = n[2]
        
        pose_pub.publish(output_pose)
```

I should note that this can eat up a lot of resources since you'll be having to loop over the pointcloud multiple times per message.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. But how will i fill the quaternion of PoseStamped?

Comment: I also edited my post.